# Exception in Initializer Error with Builder pattern

Tags: java, for-loop, dictionary, enums, builder

I have a builder constructor. I was looking for a way to shorten several not dissimilar declarations that would otherwise take up a lot of lines of code and this is an example of what I came up with. Element is a separate enum set and the idea is to loop through it and to add the values to the `HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers` outside of the method.

It complies fine but I get the titled runtime exception for `multipliers.put(e, 1.0)` . The Element enum definitely exists and is within the same file. A question with a similar name simply answers "goes crazy if something goes wrong in the static block" this seems abstract and unhelpful. The map here would only apply to instances of the class the Builder is assigned to, which is why I included it in the constructor. What am I missing?

These are all meant as examples that hopefully help replicating the problem:

```
public enum Element {
    ALPHA("Alpha"),
    BETA("Beta"),
    GAMMA("Gamma"),
    DELTA("Delta")

    public final String name;

    Element(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

The Type class

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Type {
    String name;
    HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers;

    Type(Builder p) {
        name = p.name; multipliers = p.multipliers;
    }

    static class Builder {
        final String name;
        HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers;

        public Builder(Element element) {
            this.name = element.name;
            // Default values
            for (Element e : Element.values()) {
                multipliers.put(e, 1.0);
            }
        }
        public Builder nullify(Element... elements) {
            for (Element e : elements) { multipliers.put(e, 0.0); }
            return this;
        }
        public Type generate() { return new Type(this); }
    } 
}
```

and in TypeChecker, declared outside of main I have lines similar to:

```
static Type premier = new Type.Builder(Element.ALPHA)
    .nullify(Element.GAMMA, Element.DELTA)
    .generate();
```

Comment: Can you pls print the stack trace

Comment: It looks like some variable is not initialized. Please check your code to see if either element or multipliers is null. If you are not able to locate , please paste more code to see how you initialize and call your Builder constructor

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There's no sense in us guessing what's wrong with code that you haven't given us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Runtime Exception for `multipliers.put(e, 1.0)` which is a  `java.lang.NullPointerException` because you din't initialize `multipliers` Map.

If you don't initialize any object ,by default they initialized with a `null` value.

Initialize it-

```
 HashMap<Element, Double> multipliers =new HashMap<Element, Double>();
```

Comment: I'm so moved at how simple a mistake that was and how long I've been looking at all the wrong things and useless adding 'fix' methods all over the place. Thank you.